# Emacs: Ansi-term not tab-completing

Tags: emacs

I have recently installed a few packages so that I can program iOS apps from emacs, but I am having some trouble. One of the packages (I'm pretty sure it's autocomplete) is preventing tab-completion from working in ansi-term. Any time I try to tab-complete, I get the error "Wrong type argument: characterp, tab".

Here is my .emacs file:

```
; Add packages
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/packages")

(require 'package)

; Package sources
(add-to-list 'package-archives 
    '("marmalade" .
      "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives
    '("melpa" .
            "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)

(package-initialize)

; Check packages were loaded
(require 'linum-relative)
(require 'git-gutter-fringe)
(require 'yasnippet)
(require 'auto-complete-config)

; Enable packages
(elscreen-start)

; Config
; Color scheme
(load-file "~/.emacs.d/themes/color-theme-wombat.el")

; Enable snippets
(yas-global-mode 1)

; Copy/paste with the system clipboard
(setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)

; Enable relative line numbers
(global-linum-mode t)

; Enable git gutter
(global-git-gutter-mode t)
(setq git-gutter-fr:side 'left-fringe)

; Darker git gutter colors
(set-face-foreground 'git-gutter-fr:modified "#ccaa8f")
(set-face-foreground 'git-gutter-fr:added    "#333366")
(set-face-foreground 'git-gutter-fr:deleted  "#e5786d")

; C-x -> arrow changes windows
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x <up>") 'windmove-up)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x <down>") 'windmove-down)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x <right>") 'windmove-right)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x <left>") 'windmove-left)

; Hide everything that isn't text
(tool-bar-mode -1)
(scroll-bar-mode -1)
(menu-bar-mode -1)

; Move backups
(setq backup-directory-alist
  `((".*" . ,"~/.emacsbackups")))
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
  `((".*" ,"~/.emacstemps" t)))
(setq backup-by-copying t)

; Autocomplete settings
;when to use autocomplete (note yasnippits)
(setq-default ac-sources '(ac-source-yasnippet ac-source-abbrev ac-source-dictionary ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers))
(global-auto-complete-mode t)
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'objc-mode) ; For iOS dev
```

Comment: Type `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and try hitting tab again.  That should give you a backtrace buffer that should be useful in finding the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it's yasnippet that's causing problems... I'll look into it

Comment: I found this which describes the same problem, but the suggested fix didn't solve the problem for me:
https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet/issues/289

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Alright, I fixed it. The problem was with yasnippets, but the suggestion on the link didn't work. For some reason setting yas-minor-mode to -1 didn't work. What I had to do was set yas-dont-activate to something.

Suggested fix that did NOT work for me:

```
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook (lambda()
                (yas-minor-mode -1)))
```

What DID work for me:

```
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook (lambda()
        (setq yas-dont-activate t)))
```

I'm running emacs 23.4.1

Answer (score 3):

The method provided by user1539179 works by inactiving yasnippets mode while using the shell mode. There is a small problem that I can no longer use the yasnippet mode after I open ansi-term. For example, if a markdown file is opened after the ansi-term, the yasnippet will not work. My solution is not using yasnippet globally, but hook to the mode we want to. Here is my emacs configure for yasnippet that I only bind it to `prog-mode`, `ess-mode`, and `markdown-mode`, and the tab-completing works in ansi-term.

```lisp
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-reload-all)
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'yas-minor-mode)
(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook 'yas-minor-mode)
(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook 'yas-minor-mode)
```